# How to copy/move recorded audio file from temp location to PERSISTENT location in cordova iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am recording audio using cordova mediaCapture plugin, it stores the recorded audio in temp location. Since the file is stored in temporary location, it gets deleted by OS when the app is closed. So I want to transfer it to PERSISTENT location of iOS.

Can someone please help on how to move/copy that recording from temp to new(PERSISTENT) location in cordova.